# How to fix "The getter 'docs' isn't defined for the type 'DocumentSnapshot'."?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Guys I'm having a litle trouble with Firebase updates when trying to listen to a document change, in my case it's the `event.docs`, it says `The getter 'docs' isn't defined for the type 'DocumentSnapshot'`. Checked the miggration guide but was unnable to find the modification on code.

here is my code:

```
  void _listenToOrders() {
     _subscription = userOrdersRef.doc(authUser.id).snapshots().listen((event) {
     orders.clear();
     for (final doc in event.docs) {
          orders.add(Order.fromDocument(doc));
      }

      print(orders);
    });
   }
```

Do you guys have any idea what is the new way to access these documents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is telling you that `event` is a [DocumentSnapshot](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot-class.html) type object.  As you can see from the linked API documentation, it doesn't have a property called "docs".  It's not a [QuerySnapshot](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QuerySnapshot-class.html) (which does have zero or more "docs").  The DocumentSnapshot contains just one document: the document you referenced in `userOrdersRef.doc(authUser.id)`.

Since you are only going to get one document from a DocumenSnapshot listner, there is no need to try to iterate anything.  Just use the DocumentSnapshot as-is.

```
  void _listenToOrders() {
     _subscription = userOrdersRef.doc(authUser.id).snapshots().listen((snapshot) {
     orders.clear();
     orders.add(Order.fromDocument(snapshot));
     print(orders);
  }
```